# After detecting a dictionary key has previously been received as input, modifying the first item in the list that is that key's value

Tags: python

I'm building a while loop that will allow a user to input ingredients from recipes, along with a numerical value and a measurement, to end up with a dictionary like this:

```
while program_run:

    ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
    anamount = input("Give me an amount: ")
    unitmeas = input("Give me a unit of measurement: ")

    ingredients[ingredient] = [anamount, unitmeas]

# ingredients = {'coriander': [2, 'tsp'], 'cumin': [1, "TB"], ... }
```

But I'm stuck on how to allow for a user to enter the same ingredient more than once, which is likely to happen since lots of recipes contain the same ingredients. Once the presence of a previously entered ingredient has been detected, what's a good way to add the corresponding amount to index 0 of the list that is the value of the already-entered-ingredient's key? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys but you could get around it by having a dictionary of tuples or any other structures you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement.

```
while program_run:
    ingredient = input("Give me an ingredient: ")
    anamount = input("Give me an amount: ")
    unitmeas = input("Give me a unit of measurement: ")

    if ingredients.get(ingredient): # Check if entry exists
        ingredients[ingredient][0] += anamount # If key exists, add amount
    else:
        ingredients[ingredient] = [anamount, unitmeas]
```

Note: You may need to consider the case where two inputs are the same ingredient but different units of measurement.

Comment: Sure hope the `unitmeas` is the same or you might be adding teaspoons to tablespoons

Comment: Thanks! So at first this was concatenating the amounts, giving me '22' after entering '2', which I fixed with int() around anamount, and when it still wasn't working I realized you had taken out my additional 
`ingredients[ingredient] = [anamount, unitmeas]`
So it's all good now. Thanks again!

Comment: And yes @donkopotamus, dealing with `unitmeas` is my next task!